# GMail app not displaying signature

Tags: gmail, email, exchange, signature-error

**Issue:**

When replying or creating a new email, the signature does not load.

How to replicate:

```
From the GMail app:
Settings - mail@mail.com - Signature - set any text - create a new message
```

Notes: there's no Google Account set on this phone. The GMail and Google Play Services APKs were downloaded from APKMirror

What has been tried:

- Setting up Exchange and YahooMail accounts
- Clearing the app's data and reinstalling it
- Restarting the phone
- Changing the phone's language from Brazilian Portuguese to English (United States)

What else can I try?

Thanks in advance

GMail versions tested:

```
7.5.21.158049789.release
7.5.7.156101332.release
```

Google Play Services versions tested:

```
10.2.91 (430-144333517)
11.0.55 (430-156917137)
```

Device:

```
Moto G4 Play (harpia)
```

Android version installed:

```
6.0.1 (stock, non-rooted)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestions given by [Gmail Help (website)](https://support.google.com/inbox/forum/AAAAg4HSpy4r6frVlZ1OAg/?hl=en) forum  just double these issues:

- Make sure you are not using an alias email to send your emails
- Usually the signature does not show when drafting a message but is appended when sending (try tapping 3 dots at th bottom of message and check
  if see the signature)
- Sometimes its the way the app is designed:

> The signature does not show during drafting a message it is appended
>   upon sending.
>
> Try checking  in your "Sent Mail" and if you don't see the signature,
>   there are three faint dots at the bottom of the message, click that
>   and you will see the signature.

Sources:

1. [Why is my inbox signature not showing in my email after I send](https://support.google.com/inbox/forum/AAAAg4HSpy4r6frVlZ1OAg/?hl=en)
2. [Signature hidden by "three dots"](https://support.google.com/mail/forum/AAAAK7un8RU6BTqeQ3UybM/?hl=en)
3. [Adding a signature to reply and forward emails](https://support.google.com/mail/forum/AAAAK7un8RUfDrCXAyUIHk/?hl=en)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear on that point, but the signature is really not shown/loaded. There are no "three dots". This is a random bug that I couldn't find in any other place, and it's happening with only a few phones in the company I'm working. I even factory-reset one of them, but the issue persisted.